# Strange Compiler Error with Collectors.toMap() : reference to method is ambiguous, both Map and List match

Tags: java, java-stream, javac

This class doesn't compile (using javac 17 or 21), because the second invocation of `set()` is allegedly ambiguous, while the first one is OK:

```java
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class ListVsMap {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        set(List.of("foo", "bar", "baz")
                .stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                        l -> l,
                        l -> l,
                        (x, y) -> y)));

        set(List.of("foo", "bar", "baz")
                .stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                        l -> l,
                        l -> l,
                        (x, y) -> y,
                        HashMap::new)));
    }

    public static void set(Map<String, String> valueMap) {}

    public static void set(List<String> values) {}
}
```

The error message is

```
ListVsMap.java:17: error: reference to set is ambiguous
        set(List.of("foo", "bar", "baz")
        ^
  both method set(Map<String,String>) in ListVsMap and method set(List<String>) in ListVsMap match
1 error
```

I don't understand this error.

The only difference between both invocations is the Supplier `HashMap::new` in `Collectors.toMap()`.

But the first version of `toMap()` actually calls the second one internally, and both declarations seem identical, except for some variation in the generics.

List and Map are distinct types, so type erasure can't be the reason that the compiler can't choose the correct method.

Is it a bug in javac?

Edit: I use javac of Eclipse Temurin (Adoptium)

Comment: It works with Eclipse, but not with `javac`. The problem is known; `collect` is a generic method and its `HashMap::new` argument a method reference to an overloaded constructor while the target type depends on the choice of the overloaded `set` method. This circular dependency is not resolved, by definition; I’m surprised that Eclipse somehow does this. When you replace `HashMap::new` with `() -> new HashMap<>()`, the constructor is chosen explicitly and everything compiles fine.

Comment: @Holger *`The problem is known.`* Could you provide a link to the bug report?

Comment: @WJS I didn’t say that this is a bug.

Comment: @holger.  *`It works with Eclipse, but not with javac`*.  Ok, how about where this non-bug behavior is discussed or explained.

Comment: @WJS [here is a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47276988/2711488) where I gave [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47281448/2711488) with links to the specification. I *think*, this is what applies here, but the specification is quite complex and since Eclipse exhibits a different behavior, I’m reluctant to say who is wrong or right here. Please be patient with me, searching Stackoverflow is hard. I think, there are better Q&As about this topic.

Comment: @Holger  Thanks for taking the time.  It is greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Maybe it’s valid here to use the target type of `HashMap::new` (`Supplier`) to select  the right constructor based on its arity. In that case, `javac` would be wrong. It’s a tough topic…

Comment: When I assign the results of stream collection to variables using 'var' and pass those to set(), the code compiles. Both turn out to be HashMap, which is expected. If the compiler manages to determine the var types, it should also be able to choose the variant of set(), HasMap being a subtype of Map and not List.

Comment: Unfortunately, it’s not that easy. The rules for stand-alone types, like when you assign the expression to a variable with `var`, are different than the rules for “poly expressions” like arguments for a method invocation. For example, you can easily invoke a method expecting `Map<Object, Object>` instead of `Map<String,String>` in your example. The target type determines the result type of the `collect` method in that case. There is no rule that says “if that fails, try the stand-alone type of the subexpression”. And compilers must follow rules strictly, even if something looks obvious to us.